Laravel: insert null value in Boolean type column
Database table Column type is Boolean and nullable.
Value inserting to value is true or false:
$statusVal = $request->input('status');

if($statusVal == "yes"){
    $toInsert = true;
}else if($statusVal == "no"){
    $toInsert = false;
}

ServiceDetail::create(['status' => $toInsert]);

I want to insert null to $toInsert, if status is not selected
Please guide me through this

Show entire code block where you are doing this operation.if status has value then you want to store it's value(i.e true,false).In case status is not not selected then you want to insert null.Right?

@Olivier $toInsert is used in create query

@Subha if status is not selected then I want to insert null

@Olivier ServiceDetail::create(['status' => $toInsert]);

Did you try $toInsert = null;?

@MuhammadRohail,okay,got you. I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know.

You can do it with a single statement using nested-ternary-operator.
Just do it.
$statusVal = $request->input('status');

$toInsert = empty($statusVal) ? null 
            : ($statusVal == 'yes' ? true : false);

Try this, it will work.

$toInsert = empty($statusVal) ? null : $statusVal == 'yes'; is enough.

@Olivier Yes ,that is too, even better.

$statusVal = $request->input('status');

if($statusVal == "yes"){
    $toInsert = true;
}

if($statusVal == "no"){
    $toInsert = false;
}

if(is_null($statusVal)){
    $toInsert = null;
}

